# Plotting a solution of the Allee Effect

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am doing a project on the [Allee Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allee_effect). I am able to successfully create a stability analysis. That is, I can find the relevant equilibrium points ($y_e = 0,\ y_e = \alpha$ and $y_e=k$) and draw approximation curves. However, I am having trouble plotting the solution.

The differential equation is 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}  = r y \left( 1 - \frac{y}{k} \right) \left(\frac{y}{\alpha} -1 \right)
$$

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == r y[x] (1 - y[x]/k) (y[x]/a - 1), y, x]
```

Will produce the output:

> ```
> {{y -> Function[{x}, 
>     InverseFunction[
>       Log[#1]/(a k) + Log[-a + #1]/(a (a - k)) + Log[-k + #1]/(
>         k (-a + k)) &][-((r x)/(a k)) + C[1]]]}}
> ```

where `a`, `r`, and `k` are constants depending on the population. 
When I try to plot `sol` using the code

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1}], {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It will output an empty.I was told to use the manipulate function for the constants. Please can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustrative purposes and modify as desired: rate limits,starting populationm carrying capacity etc:

```
f[a_, k_, r_, n0_] := 
 First@NDSolve[{y'[t] == r y[t] (1 - y[t]/k) (y[t]/a - 1), 
    y[0] == n0}, y[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. f[a, 1, rate, pop0]], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"time", "population"}],
   Plot[ {rate n (1 - n) (n/a - 1), rate n (1 - n)}, {n, 0, 1.1}, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.02/a, 0.02/a}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"N", "dN/dt"}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Allee effect", "Logistic"}]}
  ], {a, 0.05, 1}, {pop0, 0.2, 0.5}, {rate, 0.1, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not define **all** constants Plot cannot produce any points - how woud it know what to compute? Try

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == r y[x] (1 - y[x]/k) (y[x]/a - 1), y, x];

Plot[Evaluate[
  y[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, a -> 1, k -> 1/2, r -> 1}], {x, .51, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```